Understanding regular Borel measures
As stated in the title I want to understand/make sense of the definition of regular borel measures.
Let $X$ be locally compact and $\Omega$ the borel algebra of $X$.
Let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $(X, \Omega)$.
We say $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure if
a) $\mu(K) < \infty$ for every compact $K \subseteq X$.
b)
for $E \in \Omega$, $\mu(E)=sup\{\mu(K): K \subseteq E$ where $K$ is a compact set}
c)
$E \in \Omega$, $\mu(E)=inf\{\mu(U): E \subseteq U$ where $U$ is open}
I am trying to unerstand, how one can "use" those 3 conditions when working with regular borel measures. I don't know how relevant the context is but to mention it, I want to study the dual of $C_0(X)$. But primarily at the moment I want to understand regular borel measures.
About condition a):
I did a little bit of googleing an this property seems to be called locally finite.
But I do not understand what can one do with this property and why do we require this to hold only for compact sets.
About condition b):
One thing I have been thinking about property b) is that it enables us to approximate any set in the $\sigma$-algebra by considering a sequence of  increasing compact sets $(K_1 \subseteq K_2 \subseteq ...)$ which is bounded by $E$.
Still, I do not see why we want compact sets.
About conditon c)
My thoughts about this are the analoguos as in condition $b)$ where we just change $sup$ with $inf$ and use decreasing sequence of open sets.
Again, I do not see why we want open sets this time.
To sumarize my questions are:
What can one do with the conditions $a)$,$b)$ and $c)$. To be more precise, what do those properties enable us to do. Especially as pointed out, why do we require property $a)$ only for compact sets. Why do we consider in property $b)$ only compact subsets in the supremum, and similarly why only open sets in the infimum in $c)$.

I don't know if this will suffice as an answer (possibly rooted in the fact that it's a rather philosophical question and the answer being influenced by my viewpoint on it) but it's too long for a comment...
Note that the Lebesgue measure has all of these properties, so they are not completely arbitrary.
Why compact sets? Compact sets are somehow the best notion of "small" sets we have in a topological space (the smallest subsets $\emptyset, \{x\}, x\in X$ of a topological space$X$ are all compact). In Heine-Borel topological vector spaces (like $\mathbb R^n$) these are closed and bounded sets. But lacking the structure of a topological vector space, generally we have no better notion of "boundedness" in a general topological space and compactness will be the next best thing. This is also the reason why we often look at locally compact spaces: because there are sufficiently many "small" sets building up our space and we best understand things that are small. In particular we have a notion of "small" neighbourhoods.
Why locally finite? In this philosophy of compact sets being small, it is a quite natural assumption that small sets should have finite measure. The term "locally" normally refers to a notion of (small) open neighbourhoods, i.e. the measure is locally finite if for each $x\in X$ there is a neighbourhood $U_x\subseteq X$ of $x$ such that $\mu(U_x) < \infty$. Covering a compact set $K$ by finitely many open sets $U_x, x\in F\subseteq K$, $F$ finite, we find $\mu(K)<\infty$. On the other hand, since $X$ is locally compact, then each point $x\in X$ has a compact neighbourhood $K_x$ and thus an open neighbourhood $U_x\subseteq K_x$ with $\mu(U_x)\leq \mu(K_x) <\infty$, so these notions coincide.
Why inner regularity? The idea is now to approximate the mass of larger sets by smaller sets.
Why open sets? Coming from studying continuous functions one is often led to think that open sets are somehow small (think $\epsilon$-$\delta$-arguments). However, open sets are actually a much better notion of "large" sets in $X$. By definition $X$ is open; but also think about neighbourhood bases: each neighbourhood of a point must contain such a basis set, so that we can't make open sets "arbitrarily small" (except maybe in the discrete topology...). Even though in $\mathbb R$ the sets $]-\epsilon, \epsilon[$ may feel small (they have a small Lebesgue measure) but they still the contain a whole lot of points (a whole $\epsilon$-ball).
Why outer regularity? Well now it feels like we approximate mass of a set by shrinking larger sets containing it.
Ultimately it comes down to the following: While the topology and the measure $\mu$ are somewhat connected (by definition of the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on which $\mu$ lives), they are not intimately married. The conditions $a)$ to $c)$ interlock measure theoretic thinking with the topological thinking.
You said you want to study the dual of $C_0(X)$. You'll find out that the (continuous) linear functionals on $C_0(X)$ can be identified with complex regular measures on $X$ via
$$
\mu \mapsto \bigg[f\mapsto \int_X f\ d\mu\bigg].
$$
The thing about the dual is that we consider continuous linear functionals. This continuity is a topological property which descends to the regularity of the considered measures. This is the marriage of topology and measure theory I alluded to earlier.
Edit: If $\mu$ is any complex measure on $\Omega$, then
$$
\left\vert\int_X f\ d\mu\right\vert \leq \int_X |f|\ d|\mu| \leq \|f\|_\infty \|\mu\|
$$
so that we get a continuous linear functional $\phi\colon f\mapsto\int_X f\ d\mu$. This tells us that the space $C_0(X)$ is simply not large enough to distinguish $\mu$ from a regular measure $\mu_\phi$ given by the isomorphism $C_0(X)'\cong M_{reg}(X)$, where $M_{reg}(X)$ denotes the space of regular complex measures on $\Omega$. Thus we need the regularity condition on $\mu_f$ in order to get a unique measure representing $\phi$ (so that we indeed get an isomorphism of $C_0(X)'$ with a suitable space of measures; the space of all complex measures is too large). The regularity of a measure $\nu$ will yield that $C_c(X)\subseteq L^1(X, |\nu|)$ is dense and this allows us to argue uniqueness.
Edit 2: Regarding an application I provide the following simple example: Define
$$
O = \bigcup \{U\subseteq X\text{ open} : \mu(U) = 0\}
$$
then $\mu(O)=0$. In fact, let $K\subseteq O$ be compact, then we can cover it by finitely many open subsets $U\subseteq X$ with measure $0$, thus $\mu(K)=0$. Thanks to inner regularity we thus see $\mu(O)=0$. This shows that the support of a (regular) measure $\text{supp}\mu = X\setminus O$ is the smallest closed set such that $\mu(X\setminus\text{supp}\mu) = 0$ and hence when integrating on $X$, we can actually just integrate on $\text{supp}\mu$.
